# Get type of VarDecl in Clang Tidy Check

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree

I'd like to be able to set up a check in clang tidy such that given some variable (my_var) I can check if it matches a specific typedef (e.g. uint16_t) or the underlying type of the typedef (if integral or float).

Rational is a bit silly, our team requires that code be checked in using system hungarian notation (e.g. uint32_t lMyVar = 0;)  I don't think it's worth our time to maintain the notation, but I lost that fight, so now I'm wanting to automate that maintenance away.  I also figure it's a decent way to get started with clang and clang-tidy.

I've started off with writing a simple matcher to get VarDecls:

`Finder->addMatcher(varDecl().bind("var"),this);`

From there I don't really know what to do with the Matched decl.  Running `MatchedDecl->dump()`, but things like `MatchedDecl->getType()`  son't seem as helpful as I would hope.  Any suggestions from people more experienced with Clang AST?

Comment: What's the problem with `MatchedDecl->getType()`? `QualType` is a bit tricky to work with, but should provide all the information you need.

Comment: @SebastianRedl   Thanks.  Part of it was, once I had the QualType from getType() I didn't know what to do with it.  I was mostly using GDB to poke around, and wasn't having a great deal of luck as to where to go next.  I figured out how to get the first typedef, but still trying to figure out how to get nested typedefs (e.g. typedef my_type int16_t; my_type my_var;)  I'd like to know if my_var is based on int16_t or equivalent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this matcher:

```
Finder->addMatcher(varDecl().bind("var"),this);
```

Can use this to get the name of the first typedef in the check function:

```
const auto* MatchedDecl       = Result.Nodes.getNodeAs<VarDecl>("var");
auto        MatchedType       = MatchedDecl -> getType();
auto        MatchedIdentifier = MatchedType.getBaseTypeIdentifier();
auto        VarType           = MatchedIdentifier -> getName();
```